# How to Bind ItemsSource with ObservableCollection in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

In my WPF Application - I add new item to `ObservableCollection` via `Button Click Event Handler`. Now i want to show this added item immediately as it adds to  `ObservableCollection` via `Binding` to `ItemsControl` I wrote code but it is not working. Can anyone solve my problem. Here code is:

**.XAML File**

```
    <dxlc:ScrollBox VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ItemsControl x:Name="lstItemsClassM" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=topp,   Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Button Content="{Binding Name}"  Tag="{Binding PKId}"/>
                      </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>

    </dxlc:ScrollBox>
```

**.CS FILE**

```
     public ObservableCollection<ClassMM> topp { get; set; }

    int dv , startindex, lastindex;

    public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        topp = new ObservableCollection<ClassMM>();
        startindex=dv=1;
        topp.Add(new ClassMM() {  PKId=dv, Name = "Test 1" });
        dv=2;
        topp.Add(new ClassMM() { PKId = dv, Name = "Test 2" });
        dv = 3;
        topp.Add(new ClassMM() { PKId = dv, Name = "Test 3" });

        dv = 4;
        topp.Add(new ClassMM() { PKId = dv, Name = "Test 4" });

        lastindex=dv = 5;
        topp.Add(new ClassMM() { PKId = dv, Name = "Test 5" });


    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        lastindex = dv = dv++;

        topp.Add(new ClassMM() { PKId = dv, Name =  musavebutton.Content.ToString() });
        foreach (var jk in topp.ToList())
        {
            MessageBox.Show(jk.Name);
        }
    }
     public class ClassMM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string _name;
    public int _pkid;


    public int PKId
    {
        get { return _pkid; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _pkid)
            {
                _pkid = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }



    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _name)
            {
                _name = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }



    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
     }
   }
```

}

Comment: My guess is your MainWindow need to implement iNotifyPropertyChanged.   But the NotifyPropertyChanged on set in the answer from HichemCSharp is not required (but it does not hurt).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep your XAML as original and modify you cs as follows :

```
 public ObservableCollection<ClassMM> topp { get; set; }

        private int dv, startindex, lastindex;

        public MainWindow()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
            topp = new ObservableCollection<ClassMM>();
            startindex = dv = 1;
            topp.Add(new ClassMM() {PKId = dv, Name = "Test 1"});
            dv = 2;
            topp.Add(new ClassMM() {PKId = dv, Name = "Test 2"});
            dv = 3;
            topp.Add(new ClassMM() {PKId = dv, Name = "Test 3"});

            dv = 4;
            topp.Add(new ClassMM() {PKId = dv, Name = "Test 4"});

            lastindex = dv = 5;
            topp.Add(new ClassMM() {PKId = dv, Name = "Test 5"});


        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            lastindex = dv = dv++;

            topp.Add(new ClassMM() { PKId = dv, Name = musavebutton.Content.ToString() });
            foreach (var jk in topp.ToList())
            {
                MessageBox.Show(jk.Name);
            }
        }

        public class ClassMM : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public string _name;
            public int _pkid;


            public int PKId
            {
                get { return _pkid; }
                set
                {
                    if (value != _pkid)
                    {
                        _pkid = value;
                        NotifyPropertyChanged("PKId");
                    }
                }
            }



            public string Name
            {
                get { return _name; }
                set
                {
                    if (value != _name)
                    {
                        _name = value;
                        NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
                    }
                }
            }



            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

            protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
            {
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: No. See--Carefully! topp is `ObservableCollection` list. i want to bind this to `itemsSource` of `ItemsControl`

Comment: public ObservableCollection<ClassMM> topp { get; set; } is a property of type ObservableCollection. It for sure needs to populate changes when made using NotifyPropertyChanged method. You have to bind context as I mentioned in my answer. Try is and let us know.

Comment: Why you are writing datatype of `topp` as `integer`?

Comment: So sorry, my bad. i copied the second property you made and worked on it =)

Comment: As been said you need to set DataConxtext to the class holding the property topp. Its been a while since I wrote WPF but shouldn't you remvove Path in the XAML, i.e. 
        <ItemsControl x:Name="lstItemsClassM" ItemsSource="{Binding topp,   Mode=TwoWay}

Comment: Thank's But what to write here data type of propertyName instead of `ObservableCollection` - - -  `protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(ObservableCollection propertyName )
{  . . . `

Comment: @HichemCSharp are you here?

Comment: @HichemCSharp i removed `path` and that doesn't work. Your code is generating Exception:(

Comment: I don't know why you've NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName ) and using NotifyPropertyChanged() empty. remove this: = "" and correct your dependent code using the property name each time. please put the path again and just change topp property with the one provided and add the DataContext line to the cs file.

Comment: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. and it then points to `topp.Add(new ClassMM() {  PKId=dv, Name = "Test 1" });`

Answer (score 3):

This is incorrect: `ItemsSource="{Binding topp, Mode=TwoWay}"`. `TwoWay` pertains to getting and setting the bound property itself, in this case `topp`, rather than the contents of the list. `ObservableList` handles item add/remove notifications out of the box. In this case you don't want the items control to mess with the value of `topp`, so the correct binding is just `{Binding topp}`.